# How to install nvidia 340 driver on 23.04?

Tags: 23.04

i've reinstalled my os for 10 times trying to install this driver on my computer, is there any actual solution that wont break my computer?, my pc is p5kpl am in roem si, with nvidia geforce 9600 gt. i tried every solution but every one of them had me reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: There is no practical way. Nvidia-340 is too old, it has been depricated at the end of 2019, and is only available, tested and supported in 20.04 with the original kernel 5.4.